# Is it possible to indicate direction of object in android map polyline using Native Android Map v2?

Tags: android, google-maps

I used Google Map API V2 to draw polyline on Google Map. This polyline connected my all markers properly. But i need to show arrow mark on polyline to indicate the movement of object.

- Is it possible to do in Native Android Map V2 API? or Do I want to move Webview google Maps?
- I read [webview Map not support pinch option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947253/use-google-maps-javascript-api-in-a-webview-or-mapview-directlyadvantages-and-d),so Zoom In,Zoom out options are  availble in buttons only.Is it true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what I know Google Map API V2 does not support directional `polylines` for current time, and I think there is an issue open for this:

[code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4884](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4884) 
(Thanks @MaciejGórski)

I never used webView map so I have no idea.

**UPDATE**

Recently, Google implemented this feature for polylines in Google Maps Android API v2 and marked issue 4884 as Fixed.

They added the ability to customize the start and end caps of polylines with a custom bitmap. Using this, you will be able to add arrowheads to your polylines.

See information about Line Caps in the [Shapes Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes#line_caps). See an [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/polygon-tutorial#add_custom_styling_to_your_polyline) in the Polylines and Polygons tutorial.

You can also read the corresponding blog post here:

https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2017/02/styling-and-custom-data-for-polylines.html